# obter nome e propriedades fontes instalada no windows em delphi

Tags: delphi

eae galera blz?

estou querendo obter as propriedade das fontes instalada no windows utilizando o delphi.

ja conseguir obter todas as fontes em um listBox agora preciso pegar o nome e extensão da fonte.

```
//lista todas as fontes.
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items := Screen.Fonts;
end;

//mostrar o nome fa fonte em um label.
procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
  Label1.Font.Name := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
end;
```

esse o codigo que estou ultilizando pra vizualizar todas as fontes, agora preciso pega o nome e extenção da mesma.

Comment: Não seria melhor listar os arquivos da pasta do windows? Ou caso o seu objeto "Screen" já contenha a informação, você pode adicionar um ponteiro junto ao item inserido no listbox , recuperando o valor e acessando novamente o objeto Screen.

Comment: Então Leonardo, eu preciso obter exatamente o nome e extensão da fonte, pra esta gravando em um banco. 
Exemplo:

a Fonte Arial tem na sua propriedade o nome dessa forma "arial.ttf" 
preciso prega isso, pq o sistema que estou utilizando necessita consumir a fonte dessa forma "arial.ttf"

Comment: Você já tem uma lista com o valor "arial.ttf" e etc? é a mesma lista "Screen"?

Comment: esse esta sendo meu problema Leonado, e pega o valor "arial.ttf", quero obter justamente esse valor ai, o screen esta mostrando o nome da fonte  segundaria. exemplo:
Comic Sans MS = comic.ttf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz muito tempo que encostei o Delphi, estou meio desatualizado, mas consegui este código de exemplo na internet e funciona. Você tem de executar o aplicativo com permissões a nível de administrador:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Regkey : TRegistry;
begin
  Regkey := TRegistry.Create;
  Regkey.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  Regkey.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts', true);

  if (Regkey.ValueExists(Listbox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex] + ' (TrueType)')) then begin
    ShowMessage(Regkey.ReadString(Listbox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex] + ' (TrueType)'));
  end else begin
    ShowMessage('Font file name not found');
  end;

  Regkey.CloseKey;
end;
```

Suponho que a partir daí dê pra você dar continuidade ao projeto, mas qualquer dúvida só falar.

Comment: Depois que botar este pra funcionar, você também pode pegar as fontes .otf mudando o "(TrueType)" do registro para "(OpenType)". Abra este caminho no regedit que você verá lá mais claramente.

Comment: O mano muito Obrigado, era exatamente isso que estava procurando, Deus Abençoe!

Comment: @EdsonCosta, já que a minha resposta te ajudou a solucionar o seu problema, então se você não tiver mais nenhuma dúvida, poderia por favor aceitá-la? Caso ainda haja alguma dúvida ou algum ponto a esclarecer, me diga por favor para que possamos esclarecê-la.